# Get differences of two list that contain different object types using python

Tags: python

I have two lists:
`l1 = [obj1_1, obj1_2, obj1_3]`

`l2 = [obj2_1, obj2_2]`

`l1` has objects of type `obj1` while `l2` has objects of type `obj2`

I want to get the difference of these objects based on a parameter. For example,
`obj1` and `obj2` have a parameter named `id_1` and `id_2` respectively. I want to get the objects in `l1` that are not in `l2` where where we compare the objects using `id_1 == id_2`

EDIT:

I want to do this as efficient as possible, I know I can reduce `l2` to just a list of `id_2`s and do a for loop on `l1` and return the list of `obj1` in `l1` that do not exist in the list of the reduced objects.

Comment: Sorry, this is not very clear. I suggest giving some example code in which you construct these objects, and then what output you would expect.

Comment: `[item1 for item1 in l1 if item1.id_1 in [item2.id_2 for item2 in l2]]` , this nested list comprehension create list of id_2 element of all objects in list2 and for every element in l1 search if id_1 exist in this list.

Comment: Are the objects mutable or immutable?

Comment: @Steffo they are mutable

Comment: Perhaps you can compare the `__dict__` contents of the objects...?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, create a dictionary of `l2` where the id is the key:

```
d2 = { i.id_1 : i for i in l2 }
```

This is better than looping on lists, as lookup in dictionaries are `O(1)`.

Step2, loop through `l1` keeping those that are not in `l2`.

```
ldiff = [i for i in l1 if i.id_1 not in d2]
```

Comment: You never use the dict's values - why not just make it a `set`?

Comment: Yes, agreed, better with set.